# Plyer "makecall" crashes my Kivy/Buildozer application (NotImplementedError)

Tags: python, android, kivy, call

I'm making a Python3/Kivy application for Android/iOS. It scrapes informations from a website with beautifulsoup4 (with a workaround to bypass an error with htmlparser) and show them on screen with Kivy. I also add 4 buttons, 3 for social media purpose and one to give a phone number to the mobile phone module.

For that part, I use plyer defining phonecall() and the call.makecall() method.
That doesn't work at all and my application crashes on GNU/Linux or Android when I try to add that button bind. Can you help me please ?

What's imported on my main.py :

```
import sys
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')
import os
import time
import requests
import webbrowser
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config  
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
import plyer
from plyer import call
import bs4
import jnius
from jnius import autoclass
```

My main Class on main.py :

```
class ConceptruelleApp(App):

def build(self):
    """
    Scrape ConcepTruelle's website agenda and put it on screen
    4 buttons give access to website, social medias and phone number
    """
    def phonecall(self):
        """
        Make a Phone Call on Android with Plyer
        """
        call.makecall(tel=tel)
     
    def website(self):
        """
        Open ConcepTruelle's website
        """
        webbrowser.open("http://conceptruelle.fr/")

    def facebook(self):
        """
        Open ConcepTruelle's Facebook page
        """
        webbrowser.open("https://www.facebook.com/ConcepTruelle")

    def instagram(self):
        """
        Open ConcepTruelle's Instagram page
        """
        webbrowser.open("https://www.instagram.com/conceptruelle")
    
    # Main application : definition of title, labels and buttons put on a Float Layout
    fl = FloatLayout()
    lbl0 = MyTitle(text = "  [size=90][color=000000]L\'[/color][color=dd9514][i]Agenda[/i][/color] [color=000000][b]ConcepTruelle[/b][/size][/color]", markup=True, size_hint =(1, .1), pos_hint ={'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.97})
    lbl1 = MyLabel1(text = event_title_1 + "\n" + agenda1, size_hint =(1, .5), pos_hint ={'center_x':.5, 'center_y':1.03})
    lbl2 = MyLabel2(text = event_title_2 + "\n" + agenda2, size_hint =(1, .5), pos_hint ={'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.86})
    lbl3 = MyLabel1(text = event_title_3 + "\n" + agenda3, size_hint =(1, .5), pos_hint ={'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.69})
    lbl4 = MyLabel2(text = event_title_4 + "\n" + agenda4, size_hint =(1, .5), pos_hint ={'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.52})
    lbl5 = MyLabel1(text = event_title_5 + "\n" + agenda5, size_hint =(1, .5), pos_hint ={'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.35})
    fl.add_widget(lbl0)
    fl.add_widget(lbl1)
    fl.add_widget(lbl2)
    fl.add_widget(lbl3)
    fl.add_widget(lbl4)
    fl.add_widget(lbl5)
    btn1 = Button(text = "Appel", size_hint =(.25, .1), pos_hint ={'center_x':.125, 'center_y':.05})
    tel = 9999999999
    btn1.bind(on_press=phonecall(tel))
    btn2 = Button(text = "Site Web", size_hint =(.25, .1), pos_hint ={'center_x':.375, 'center_y':.05})
    btn2.bind(on_press=website)
    btn3 = Button(text = "Facebook", size_hint =(.25, .1), pos_hint ={'center_x':.625, 'center_y':.05})
    btn3.bind(on_press=facebook)
    btn4 = Button(text = "Instagram", size_hint =(.25, .1), pos_hint ={'center_x':.875, 'center_y':.05})
    btn4.bind(on_press=instagram)
    fl.add_widget(btn1)
    fl.add_widget(btn2)
    fl.add_widget(btn3)
    fl.add_widget(btn4)
    return fl
```

On my buildozer.spec :

```
requirements = python3,kivy==master,plyer,requests,beautifulsoup4,html5lib,urllib3,chardet,idna,android,pyjnius

android.permissions = INTERNET,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,CALL_PHONE,CALL_PRIVILEGED,BLUETOOTH
```

My log file :

```
12-02 10:36:13.882  4613  4708 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):

12-02 10:36:13.883  4613  4708 I python  :    File "/home/guillaume/Documents/Python/ConcepTruelle_3/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/conceptruelle/plyer/utils.py", line 96, in _ensure_obj

12-02 10:36:13.886  4613  4708 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plyer.platforms'

12-02 10:36:13.891  4613  4708 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):

12-02 10:36:13.899  4613  4708 I python  :    File "/home/guillaume/Documents/Python/ConcepTruelle_3/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 194, in <module>

12-02 10:36:13.907  4613  4708 I python  :    File "/home/guillaume/Documents/Python/ConcepTruelle_3/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/conceptruelle/kivy/app.py", line 829, in run

12-02 10:36:13.912  4613  4708 I python  :    File "/home/guillaume/Documents/Python/ConcepTruelle_3/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 133, in build

12-02 10:36:13.914  4613  4708 I python  :    File "/home/guillaume/Documents/Python/ConcepTruelle_3/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 97, in phonecall

12-02 10:36:13.916  4613  4708 I python  :    File "/home/guillaume/Documents/Python/ConcepTruelle_3/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/conceptruelle/plyer/facades/call.py", line 45, in makecall

12-02 10:36:13.918  4613  4708 I python  :    File "/home/guillaume/Documents/Python/ConcepTruelle_3/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/conceptruelle/plyer/facades/call.py", line 56, in _makecall

12-02 10:36:13.920  4613  4708 I python  :  NotImplementedError

12-02 10:36:13.921  4613  4708 I python  : Python for android ended.

12-02 10:36:14.190   848  5842 I ActivityManager: Process org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle (pid 4613) has died: fore TOP 

12-02 10:36:14.191   848  2780 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{9843b0a u0 org.conceptruelle.conceptruelle/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
```

Answer (score 1):

Asking for permissions on manifest was not enough. I solved it with those lines :

```
import android
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.CALL_PHONE])
```