# Make a call with your application in python3 kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Hi does anyone know how to make a function to call a phone number using intents in kivy? Thank you in advance.

Here is an attempt of mine to do this exact thing, is it right or do I have to add something else?

```
from jnius import autoclass

Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
Uri = autoclass('android.net.Uri')
call = None


def call_number(self):
    call = self.Intent()
    call.setAction(self.Intent.ACTION_CALL)
    call.setData(self.Uri.parse("tel:%s" % int(host_number)))
    self.startActivity(call)
```

Comment: The function will be linked to a button in the application, but the only thing I need is to find a way to use intents in python to call a phone number.

Comment: Hi @mss051, I'm facing the same issue atm. Have you managed to accomplish it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, try searching on the kivy docs or asking on their discord for extra info!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's too late now, but I figured it out. I found out about plyer module (I believe plyer is based on jnius, but with easier syntax(?)). Anyway, making a call is as simple as it gets; [plyer Call class](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/plyer/facades/call.py). Also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65106052/plyer-makecall-crashes-my-kivy-buildozer-application-notimplementederror) helped me fix the permission problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use the [kivy plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer) library for this. There's an example for calls specifically [here](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/examples/call/main.py)

Based on that, it looks like you should be able to do

```
import plyer

plyer.makecall("<phone number goes here>")
plyer.dialcall()
```